# Custom theme error will be output after data migration from Magento 1.9.3 to Magento 2.2.4

Tags: error, magento2.2, ultimo

Custom theme error will be output after data migration from Magento 1.9.3 to Magento 2.2.4.

I migrated data from Magento 1.9.3.1 to Magento 2.2.4.
No error was output at that time.
We were able to migrate the data without problems.

However, after installing and importing the Ultimo theme file and checking the front end, an error was output.

Below is the error contents.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Unable to load theme by specified key: 'ultimo/fascinate'

Exception #0 (LogicException): Unable to load theme by specified key: 'ultimo/fascinate'
#0 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/View/Design.php(148): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\FlyweightFactory->create('ultimo/fascinat...', 'frontend')
#1 /var/www/html/multistore/generated/code/Magento/Theme/Model/View/Design/Proxy.php(111): Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design->setDesignTheme('ultimo/fascinat...', 'frontend')
#2 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(148): Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design\Proxy->setDesignTheme('ultimo/fascinat...')
#3 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'default-store-h...')
#4 /var/www/html/multistore/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute(NULL)
#5 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#6 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /var/www/html/multistore/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#10 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#13 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /var/www/html/multistore/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /var/www/html/multistore/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#21 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/html/multistore/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#23 /var/www/html/multistore/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#24 /var/www/html/multistore/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#25 {main}
```

Can you teach us how to deal with it?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried : php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Check my answer it will help you. also, let me know if still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this query:

> UPDATE cms_page SET custom_theme = NULL WHERE custom_theme IS NOT NULL

This may help you.

Comment: Thank you very much.
The front end was displayed safely.

Comment: @mr.hironobu if any answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark , hit that tickmark for right ansewer that will help future readers

Answer (score 1):

Try below the steps to solve your issue.

**Step: 1**

1. Clear cache & flush cache
2. Execute again static deploy

**Step: 2**

Still, if your getting issue then follow below steps

3. Delete your theme from Database (`theme`Table)
4. Execute again static deploy content
5. Clear cache & flush cache
6. It will work. Meanwhile, your theme also be created from Database.

**Command**:

> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy